# arabic query string - url did not stored and displayed

Tags: php, url, seo

I'm trying to make my links SEO friendly by addingdate and title. However, I some of the titles are in Arabic. The English ones work great, while the Arabic ones doesn't. Example:

> خالد-على-20120923220529.html

Following [this tutorial](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/04/seo-friendly-urls-with-php.html), I've produced this code:

```
$title=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
```

i have error with insert title and URL didn't insert with Arabic character
and when removing this code inserting done no problem but when select this url from database will redirect not found 404 
i need t display my links

> http://dzeduc.org/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D9%88-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%AA%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AC%D8%AD%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D9%85%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%AC%D8%A9-1%D9%882/

How can i resolve this problem?

Note

```
$conn = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_name,$conn);

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

Meta Tags

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: @D.A.V.O.O.D I don't Know What Urldecode Any examlpe With this tutorials http://www.9lessons.info/2011/04/seo-friendly-urls-with-php.html

Comment: Article.php code not exist in your question ! but i edited my answer to solve your problem, you must do 3 items to solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should fix 3 problems :

**1.** Edit your code on `Article.php` to:

```
$url = urldecode( mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['url']) );
```

**2.** Make sure your `url` field collation is `utf_general_ci`

**3.** Edit your `.htaccess` file to:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ article.php?url=$1
```